# fatal error: linux/compiler-gcc9.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, cygwin

I am trying to compile a Linux kernel. I followed instructions and installed tools. But I am stuck at this. GCC is installed and the version is 9 but still, it says cannot find the header.
I am building on ubuntu.
If I try to use the old GCC, the new GCC 9 automatically gets installed along with old one. if I uninstall the new one then the command disappears, setting up an alias does not help.

I am really fed up with the incompatibility of this building process with windows due to header files.
How it comes that I have installed compiler and it does not have support with old commands. Like what kind of upgrade is this to GCC, you are unable to build an old source with the new version of the tool.?

anyway, I want to find a solution to this, If you know please tell me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I miss the relevance of the Cygwin tag

Comment: "I followed instructions and installed tools" What instructions and _how_ did you install tools? I assume you're using `apt-get`? The `gcc` version shouldn't matter to the kernel build. It should be able to build with whatever is the latest version for your version of the ubuntu distro. What version of ubuntu? What kernel source version? Why do you [seemingly] have _two_ versions of `gcc` installed? How  did you generate the kernel's master `.config` file?

Comment: You might have better results asking this question on https://superuser.com/ or https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: You may want to add the `linux-kernel` tag [and _remove_ the `cygwin` tag]

Comment: @CraigEstey Thanks for suggesting me this. I am not linux user. So i am not sure how this dude is having two gcc versions. I am going to your told forums. Thanks.

Comment: Good luck. I've been building kernels for years (fedora, ubuntu) and in most cases, once the requisite tools are installed, things just work. Particularly if you use a given distro's package installer to install the tools (ubuntu generally works well).